# Visual Studio 2017 SpecFlow and CodedUI Assembly Could Not Be Loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests, specflow

I have a test framework where we intend to use Codedui as well as specflow. I have setup the tools separately before, but I am currently getting an error upon running the specflow test with the two tools loaded together:

```
    [10/12/2017 12:02:00 AM Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test discovery starting
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test discovery complete
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] NUnit VS Adapter 2.1.1.0 discovering tests is started
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Warning] Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a of C:\Users\*****\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\*****\*****\bin\Debug\*****.dll not found. Can be ignored if not a NUnit project.
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] NUnit VS Adapter 2.1.1.0 discovering test is finished
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 2 found (0:00:00.2788078) ==========
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution started
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] Running selected tests in C:\Users\******\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\******\******\bin\Debug\******.dll
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] NUnit3TestExecutor converted 1 of 1 NUnit test cases
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Warning] TearDown failed for test fixture ******.Specflow.Features.SpecFlowFeature1Feature
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Warning] System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Warning]    at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.Discovery.RuntimeBindingRegistryBuilder.BuildBindingsFromType(Type type)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.Discovery.RuntimeBindingRegistryBuilder.BuildBindingsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.BuildBindingRegistry(IEnumerable`1 bindingAssemblies)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.InitializeBindingRegistry(ITestRunner testRunner)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.CreateTestRunner(Int32 threadId)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner(Int32 threadId)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner(Assembly testAssembly, Nullable`1 managedThreadId)
   at *****.Specflow.Features.SpecFlowFeature1Feature.FeatureSetup()
--TearDown
   at *****.Specflow.Features.SpecFlowFeature1Feature.FeatureTearDown()
[10/12/2017 12:02:01 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution complete
[10/12/2017 12:02:02 AM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:00.7393256) ==========
```

I have checked the references, and it seems like the "missing" reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework is listed in my references. What else could be the issue?

Comment: Did you try to resolve the issue around the missing reference.. if not would suggest that you do it first ..

Answer (score 1):

CodedUI only works with MSTest. 
To get it to work with SpecFlow, you need an additional plugin.

Please have a look at the documentation for it: http://specflow.org/documentation/Using-SpecFlow-with-CodedUI-API/
The interesting section for you would be: `Getting SpecFlow to generate the [CodedUITest] attribute with Visual Studio 2013+ and MSTest`

You need a custom SpecFlowCodedUITestGenerator which adds the needed `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute` attribute and removes the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute` attribute from the test class.

Exact steps how to do this are in the documentation.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I understand that it would be easier for people to have the answer directly here, so I added a more information to it. But the link goes to the official documentation for exactly the question of how to use CodedUI with SpecFlow. So why duplicate information, that could potentially get outdated?

Comment: This is great, but there seems to be no information as to how to get this working on a recent version of Specflow. Latest I see is 1.6 through 1.9. I'm currently using Specflow 2.2.1.